# What is the difference between washing machine belts: 1287 8PHE and 1287 8PH?

Tags: repair, washing-machine

My washing machine belt has broken. I have found two belts, sellers of which say in description that they compatible with my appliance (**Electrolux EWT9125W**).

**8PHE** belt is 3 times more expensive than **8PH**.

The broken belt is **8PHE**. But I don't know whether the washing machine had been repaired before or not. I don't know if **8PHE** was supplied by manufacturer, and couldn't find part list.
So what's the difference?

Comment: Check with the belt manufacturer.

Comment: @SolarMike, all what I found is the description of PH (https://www.chiorino.com.pl/content/uploads/2019/10/poly_v_leaflet_en_0.pdf). Unfortunately, nothing regarding E

Answer (score 2):

- Pick a retailer.
- Check their return policy for conditions acceptable to you.
- Buy the cheaper belt.
- If it doesn't work

  - Return it.
  - Buy the more expensive belt.

Odd are good that the `E` version is "extended life" or something like that, or maybe just a later revision. If the retailer claims that both fit, go with the cheaper one to save some cash, or spend more to match your designer clothes ethos, whichever you prefer.

So long as the return policy is good (for you), it's an inconvenience if the one you choose doesn't work, but no major loss.

Unfortunately, though a quick search found some parts suppliers for the Electrolux brand, none had any hits on that specific model, so I couldn't look further.